# PDO and dependency injection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, dependency-injection

I'm trying to find out the best way to use PDO with my other classes without using the singleton method. I've searched dozens of questions here on stackoverflow but it's still unclear to me on how to do it. I understand that apparently dependency injection is the way to go, but I'm not quite sure if I understand it. This is what I've come up with.

```
class MyPDO extends PDO {

    public function run($sql, $args = NULL) {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function addNew($table, $values) {
        $this->run('INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' (first_name) VALUES (?)', $values);
    }
}

class User {

    private $database = null;

    public function __construct(Database $database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function register($user) {
        $this->database->addNew('users', $user);
    }

}

$pdo = new MyPDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
$user = new User($pdo);
$user->register(array('name'));
```

I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it or not or if I'm way off base. Should the connection be made inside the MyPDO class or outside of it like it is now? Also, I'm wondering if inserting a user into the DB should be in the MyPDO class like it is now, or if I should create a function in the User class to insert into the DB. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In general, yes, this is the right approach to DI. I'd strongly question the need to `extend PDO` though, your class adds very little to nothing over a plain `PDO` connection.

Comment: I got the wrapper idea from this site here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper The guy seems to know what he's talking about so I figured I should go with that wrapper. Should I just create a class that doesn't extend PDO and still has the run/query functions inside of it then?

Comment: IMO you should use the plain PDO object **unless and until you have a really solid reason to abstract it.** Don't create some wrapper just because you think it might be a good idea without actually having identified a specific problem that it can solve.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Is any class that has database functions within it like queries considered a wrapper? Are you saying I should just make the DB connection not in a class and just pass the DB variable to the User class like in my example and run all the queries from there?

Comment: @deft Fundamentally, I applaud your attempt to go down the DI road. Now, to clear things up, when you extend a class (PDO in this case), you are not wrapping it. There are sever things about PDO that can be simplified if you create a wrapper (such as explicitly stating picking the correct data type for prepared statements, closing (setting to null) stmt objects, etc ...). But, to create a true PDO wrapper, you must inject the PDO object into a wrapping class. Then, inject this into your `user` or other classes upon instantiation. I made a PDO wrapper class, and it makes life much easier.

Comment: @deft deceze's advice is sound if you do not know what you are doing with PDO. If you know what you are doing and want to make the interface clearer, more complete, and automatic, that is your choice. The key, is that you must find a place to retain the 4 arguments that you can supply PDO upon instantiation. Some say use an .ini. Some say use an include. Bottom line, you need to be able to have all necessary arguments supplied when you do new PDO($blah , $foo, $baz, $someArray). This is where DI can fall apart with PDO. You might cheat and use a `require` in your PDO wrapper and directly ...

Comment: ... instantiate the object in the PDO wrapper class. Otherwise, figure out how to do `new PDO()` and have all the default arguments and such already set. The constructor of your PDO wrapper class can help set some things, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am that guy who wrote the MyPDO "wrapper". To answer your questions without irrelevant fuss:

> I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it or not or if I'm way off base.

Yes, it's good.

> Should the connection be made inside the MyPDO class or outside of it like it is now?

Better do it inside, because beside making a connection you will have to add some configuration options

> if inserting a user into the DB should be in the MyPDO class like it is now

By no means - NO!
Just think what it would be like if you will have even a dozen classes!

So it would be

```
class MyPDO extends PDO {

    public function __construct($dsn, $username, $password, $options) {
        $default_options = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
        $options = array_merge($default_options, $options)
        parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }

    public function run($sql, $args = NULL) {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}

class User {

    private $database = null;
    private $table = "users";

    public function __construct(Database $database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function register($user_data) {
        $this->database->run('INSERT INTO ' . $this->table . ' (first_name) VALUES (?)', $user_data);
    }
}

$pdo = new MyPDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
$user = new User($pdo);
$user->register(array('name'));
```

Comment: What about injecting a PDO object into MyPDO?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Your Common Sense. I think I'll go ahead and run with this, unless you can recommend an even better option.

Comment: For instance, not sure if a dependency injection container would be better or even necessary.

Comment: Not the most flexible solution, but I suppose it can work.

Comment: How is it not flexibe? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

**I am using PHP 5.6.x**: *This is cheating and not dependency injection*, but it might help you in the mean time. At least you can inject your PDO wrapper into other objects (User, etc). Also, this code assumes you want to use stored procedures with prepared statements.

```
abstract class Storage  //Program to an interface. Not an implementation.
{

}

abstract class Database extends Storage  //Program to an interface. Not an implementation.
{
    protected $pdo  = null;
    protected $stmt = null;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
    {
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function __destruct() 
    {   
       $this->pdo  = null;
       $this->stmt = null;
       unset($this->pdo, $this->stmt);
    }

    protected function getDSN()
    {
        return "{$this->rdms}:host={$this->host};port={$this->port};dbname={$this->dbName};charset={$this->charset};"
    }

    /* Place all wrapping methods here, etc. */

    private function validatePDOStmtObject(PDOStatement $stmt)
    {
        $this->stmt = $stmt;
        return true;
    }

    public function query($sp)
    {
        return $this->validatePDOStmtObject($this->pdo->query("CALL {$sp}"));
    }

    public function prepare($sp)
    {
         try 
         {            
            $this->validatePDOStmtObject($this->pdo->prepare("CALL {$sp}"));
         }
         catch (\PDOException $pdoEx) 
         {
             throw new \RuntimeException("Failed to prepare query / stored procedure.<br>" . print_r($this->pdo->errorInfo(), true) . $pdoEx->getTraceAsString());
         }

         return;
    }

    public function bindParam($parameter, $variable)
    {
        $dataType = null;

        if(is_string($variable))
        {
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
        elseif(is_int($variable))
        {
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
        }
        elseif(is_bool($variable))
        {
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        }
        elseif($variable === null)
        {
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_LOB;
        }

        //Where the actual binding takes place.
        if(!$this->stmt->bindParam($parameter, $variable, $dataType))
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException("Failed to bind paramenter $parameter" . print_r($this->stmt->errorInfo(), true));
        }

        return;
    }

    public function execute()
    { 
        $flag = false;

        try 
        {
            $this->stmt->execute();
            $flag = true;
        }    
        catch (\PDOException $pdoEx) 
        {
            error_log($pdoEx->getTraceAsString() . '<br><br>' . print_r($this->stmt->errorInfo(), true));
            //echo $pdoEx->getTraceAsString() . '<br><br>' . print_r($this->stmt->errorInfo(), true);
        }

        return $flag;
    }

    public function fetch()
    {
        return $this->stmt->fetch();
    }

    public function fetchColumn()
    {
        return $this->stmt->fetchColumn();
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $rows = $this->stmt->fetchAll();
        $this->clearRowsets();
        $this->stmtClose();
        return $rows;
    }

    public function clearRowsets()
    {
        if(isset($this->stmt))
        {
            while($this->stmt->fetch()) 
            {
                if(!$this->stmt->nextRowset())
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    public function stmtClose()
    {
        $this->stmt = null;
        return;
    }

    public function closeCursor()
    {
        $this->stmt->closeCursor();
        return;
    }

    public function close()
    {
        $this->pdo = null;
        return;
    }

    public function startTransaction()
    {
        if($this->pdo->beginTransaction())
        {
            //'<br>Starting PDO/MySQL transaction.<br>';
            error_log('<br>Starting PDO/MySQL transaction.<br>');
        }
        else
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to prepare the PDO statement.<br>' . print_r($this->pdo->errorInfo(), true));
        }

        return;
    }

    public function commit()
    {
        if($this->pdo->commit())
        {
            //echo '<br>Committing datbase changes.<br>';
            error_log('<br>Committing datbase changes.<br>');
        }
        else
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException('PDO was unable to commit the last statement.<br>' . print_r($this->pdo->errorInfo(), true));
        }

        return;
    }

    public function rollback()
    {
        if($this->pdo->rollback())
        {
            //echo '<br>Rolling back datbase changes.<br>';
            error_log('<br>Rolling back datbase changes.<br>');
        }
        else
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException('PDO was unable to rollback the last statement.<br>' . print_r($this->pdo->errorInfo(), true));
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Finally, you can design a concrete child class.

```
class MySQL extends Database  //Now, build you concrete implementation.
{
    protected $rdms    = 'mysql';
    protected $host    = null;
    protected $port    = null;
    protected $dbName  = null;
    protected $charset = null;

    private static $instance = null;

    // PURE DI would start here by injecting a PDO object.
    // However, the PDO object must be configured, too.
    // It is possible to do PURE PDO DI.

    public function __construct($host = null, $port = null, $dbName = null, $charset = null)
    {
        require_once 'MySQLCreds.php'; 

        //$host, $port, $dbName, and $charset can be stored in an
        //include, or be supplied as arguments to the MySQL constructor.

        $this->host    = $host;
        $this->port    = $port;
        $this->dbName  = $dbName;
        $this->charset = $charset;

        parent::__construct(new PDO($this->getDSN(), $username, $password, $options));

        // Starting here with DI is cheating, but it gets you on the
        // right track for now. Database::getDSN() is used to dynamically
        // construct the DSN.
    }

    /* Destructor */
    public function __destruct() 
    {   
        $this->rdms    = null;
        $this->host    = null;
        $this->port    = null;
        $this->dbName  = null;
        $this->charset = null;
        unset($this->rdms, $this->host, $this->port, $this->dbName, $this->charset);
        parent::__destruct();
    }

    /* Only if you wanted to make a singleton. In that case,
       make the constuctor private.
    */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
       if(!isset(self::$instance))
       {
            self::$instance = new self();
       }

       return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

You **might** instantiate this as:

```
$user = new User(new MySQL())
        //Uses an include inside of the constructor.
```

This is also possible.

```
$user = new User(new MySQL($host, $port, $dbName, $charset))
        //Externally supplied arguments.
```

Some people use a dependency injector container, factories, or singletons. Pick your poison. Whatever the case, try to implement an autoloader and use namespaces. Note: be wary of the `PDOException` this sequence can cause. Use `try/catch` as appropriate.

Oh, by the way, the constructor for `User` could look something like this.

```
abstract class Person
{
    protected $db = null;

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db
    }
}

class User extends Person
{
    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        parent::__construct($db)
    }
}
```

Technically, I could use a type hint of `Storage`, but that would require populating the `Storage` class with public interface methods that call upon uniform, concrete implementation methods (defined in child classes of Storage: Database, XMLFile, File, etc). In some cases, this is not a likely polymorphic solution. But, you can swap out any kind of database and it should sill work.

Comment: Skeptical? Read about the advantages of dependency injection in this article. http://russellscottwalker.blogspot.com/2013/09/handling-global-data-in-php-web_7.html

Comment: I'm not skeptical about dependency injection. I understand that's the way to go, I'm just unclear on what it is completely. I thought you said your example wasn't dependency injection? And unfortunately, it's a bit complex for my understanding at the moment. Also, thanks for the article.

Comment: If you read the comments, you'll see why technically this is not DI. But 99% of it is. The answer you chose is no better in that regard, but my answer is more flexible. That is, it is more flexible if you alter the `Database::prepare` and `Database::query` methods to take a parameter called `$sql`, instead of assuming the use of stored procedures.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem yesterday. I figured using dependency injections is the way to go too.

I can't tell you if my way is the best way to go, but it works perfectly fine for me.

First off your class MyPDO takes away a lot of functionally PDO offers you ([See here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/class-for-reducing-development-time/29394#29394)).

I solved my problem like this:

```
class Database {

    public $con;

    function __construct($dsn, $user, $password) {
        $this->connect($dsn, $user, $password);
    }

    private function connect($dsn, $user, $password) {

        try {

            $this->con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
            ));

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

class User {

    private $database;

    public function __construct(Database $database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function register($user) {
        $stmt = $this->database->prepare("
            INSERT INTO user (first_name)
            VALUES (:first_name)
        ");

        $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
        $first_name = $user;

        $stmt->execute();
    }

}


$database = new Database("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
$user = new User($database);
$user->register('name');
```

In my opinion the connection should be made inside the class, since the connection is the whole point of the class. It also gives you the ability to do exception handling.

Based on my experience it is better to write all statements in fitting classes. Like i did in the code above.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: OP's class actually doesn't take anything away from PDO, since it `extends` it. *Your* class on the other hand doesn't even work; your code will fail with a `Database has no prepare method` error… :)

Comment: Thats true. But why would you extend something that already has better methods. I use the prepare method in the user class. For each statment individual. [Like described here](http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension) (the third code block in this section)

Comment: Well, OP seems to think that they're adding *even more better methods* to an already *awesome* class! ;-) (I too find this extremely debatable BTW.)

Comment: To be honest I don't really know what I'm doing haha. I just came across this idea from phpdelusions.net. The other way I thought of doing it was just like @Wurstlaugen said. I'm wondering why this got a down vote? Is the method I posted above actually better?

Comment: Also, I don't see how my class takes away any functionality since like @deceze said it's extending it, whereas the example you linked me doesn't. Thanks for your help guys.